# JAVA - Use functional interface for calculations

Tags: java, functional-interface

So... this is my first post here on Stack and i'm also new into Java (into programming at all). I'm trying to make a simple commandline app that will calculate employees' profit depending of generated income. Already did it but as i'm learning functional interfaces and lambdas right now, i'd like to try use them. Down below you can find the code.

```
package BalanceCounter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Number of employees: ");
    int empCounter = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(empCounter);
    for (int i = 0; i < empCounter; i++) {
        employees.add(new Employee());
    }

    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        System.out.println("Employee: " + employee.getEmpName()
                + "\nBase salary: " + employee.getEmpBaseSalary()
                + "\nProfit from income: " + employee.getEmpBonus()
                + "\n");
    }
}
}
```

Here's Employee class with getEmpBonus() method in comment block. That's where i've tried to use functional interfaces.

```
package BalanceCounter;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Employee {
private String empName;
private double empBaseSalary;
private double empIncome;
private double empBonus;


Employee() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Employees name: ");
    setEmpName(input.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Type basic salary: ");
    setEmpSalary(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Generated income: ");
    setEmpIncome(input.nextDouble());
    setEmpBonus();

    System.out.println();
}

/*
 * Here are all the setters
 */

private void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}

private void setEmpSalary(double empBaseSalary) {
    this.empBaseSalary = empBaseSalary;
}

private void setEmpIncome(double empIncome) {
    this.empIncome = empIncome;
}

private void setEmpBonus() {
    if (getEmpIncome() <= 10000)
        empBonus = (getEmpIncome() * 3) / 100;
    else if (getEmpIncome() > 10000 && getEmpIncome() <= 20000)
        empBonus = (getEmpIncome() * 2) / 100;
    else empBonus = (getEmpIncome() * 1) / 100;
}


/*
 * Time for the getters
 */

String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}

double getEmpBaseSalary() {
    return empBaseSalary;
}

private double getEmpIncome() {
    return empIncome;
}

double getEmpBonus() {
    return empBonus;
}

/*
 * double getEmpBonus(Calculation calculation) {
 * return empBonus = calculation.calculate(this.empBonus);
 * }
 */

}
```

And the last thing is Calculation interface.

```
package BalanceCounter;


public interface Calculation {
    double calculate(double arg);
}

class CalcBonus implements Calculation{
    public double calculate(double empBonus) {
        return empBonus;
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long post but wanted to give you all informations i have.
Also if you see some mistakes and bad habits in my code - please let me know. Kind regards.

Comment: So, you want us to write this using lambda expressions and functional interfaces?

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual specific question is that you're trying to ask. Instead it seems like you're just describing in general what you have in mind for doing next on your project.

Comment: Yes, that's what i'd like you to help me with. As you see i've tried it by myself but the effect is poor. Got no problem using interface and lambda with simple types like int, String etc. Just don't know how to use there empBonus object.
@csm_dev - i'd like to do this by myself but don't know why. Sorry for not being too much specific. Maybe i should ask then... how should CalcBonus class look like to make it work.

Comment: Now I'm extra confused - you said you are fine using simple data types like String, int, etc... but then say you don't know how to use `empBonus` which is just a String. Please be more specific. If you are having errors/exceptions - tell us. If the code produces incorrect results - tell us. It seems you made an attempt but we aren't sure what is wrong with that attempt.

Comment: I don't see how lambdas are appropriate for this kind of problem.

Comment: The problem is that if i uncomment `getEmpBonus(Calculation calculation)` method in Employee class (and comment the second one) then in Main class i have missing argument in `employee.getEmpBonusInt()`. I do not know what argument it should be. The second problem is that i'd like to know how to write CalcBonus class that will use the same user data that are given from keyboard. Hope it helps somehow...

Comment: Here's exact error from IntelliJ
`Error:(24, 58) java: method getEmpBonus in class BalanceCounter.Employee cannot be applied to given types;
  required: BalanceCounter.Calculation
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This interface :

```
public interface Calculation {
    double calculate(double arg);
}
```

has the same contract that `DoubleUnaryOperator` :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface DoubleUnaryOperator {
    double applyAsDouble(double operand);
   ...
}
```

So you don't really need to introduce a new interface for this.
You could use the built-in one.
But if you want to really stress on the name and or arguments of the method.

As a general way, look before whether built-in Functional Interfaces could not match to your requirement before creating it.

Suppose now you uncomment your method and you want to use this method :

```
  double getEmpBonus(DoubleUnaryOperator calculation) {
     return empBonus = calculation.applyAsDouble(this.empBonus);
  }
```

Without lambda, you have to create a subclass or an anonymous class if you want to pass an implementation that doubles the bonus :

```
class DoubleBonus implements DoubleUnaryOperator {
    public double applyAsDouble(double operand) {
        return operand * 2;
    }
}
```

The idea of the lambda is that you could inline the subclass with a lambda expression.
You could so invoke the method in this way :

```
double doubledBonus = getEmpBonus(empBonus->empBonus*2);
```

You don't need any longer of the subclass or an anonymous class.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations and pushing me forward. Whole code was written to let me understand interfaces - just for practice. What i've found is that i can get right output by `employee.getEmpBonus(new CalcBonus())' in Main class too.

Answer (score 1):

```
package training;
public class Calculator {
    interface IntegerMath {
        int operation(int a, int b);
    }
    interface RealMath {
        double operation(double a, double b);
    }
    public int operateBinary(int a, int b, IntegerMath op) {
        return op.operation(a, b);
    }
    public double operateBinary(int a, int b, RealMath op) {
        return op.operation(a, b);
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Calculator cal = new Calculator();
        IntegerMath addition = (a, b) -> a + b;
        IntegerMath subtraction = (a, b) -> a - b;
        IntegerMath multiplication = (a, b) -> a * b;
        RealMath division = (a, b) -> a / b;
                System.out.println("Add: 40 + 22 = " +
                cal.operateBinary(40, 22, addition));
        System.out.println("Sub: 120 - 80 = " +
                cal.operateBinary(120, 80, subtraction));
        System.out.println("Mul: 12 * 12 = " +
                cal.operateBinary(12, 12, multiplication));
        System.out.println("Div: 478 / 12 = " +
                cal.operateBinary(478, 12, division));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a good practice to advocate your solution though your code may answer the question.